# Get name of highest value max()

Tags: php

How to get the name variable that is highest?
example code: max($1, $2, $3), and $2 value is "32" and its the highest, so how can I save $2 to another var?
my code:

```
$stats = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=**********&steamid='.$id); //example id - 76561198019477694
$stats = json_decode($stats, true);

$fav_gun1 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["9"]["value"];
$fav_gun2 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["10"]["value"];
$fav_gun3 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["11"]["value"];
$fav_gun4 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["12"]["value"];
$fav_gun5 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["13"]["value"];
$fav_gun6 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["14"]["value"];
$fav_gun7 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["15"]["value"];
$fav_gun8 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["16"]["value"];
$fav_gun9 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["17"]["value"];
$fav_gun10 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["18"]["value"];
$fav_gun11 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["19"]["value"];
$fav_gun12 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["20"]["value"];
$fav_gun13 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["21"]["value"];
$fav_gun14 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["22"]["value"];
$fav_gun15 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["23"]["value"];
$fav_gun16 = $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["24"]["value"];

$fav_gun = max($fav_gun1, $fav_gun2, $fav_gun3, $fav_gun4, $fav_gun5,    $fav_gun6, $fav_gun7, $fav_gun8, $fav_gun9, $fav_gun10, $fav_gun11, $fav_gun12, $fav_gun13, $fav_gun14, $fav_gun15, $fav_gun16);

// $fav_gun returns number of kills with specified gun, i want to get name of this gun ($stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["xx"]["name"])
```

Comment: Sort your array using `usort` ([Link](http://php.net/usort)) and you can have your stats nicely sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array while keeping track of the name associated with the highest value:

```
$highest_name = false;
$highest_value = false;

foreach($stats["playerstats"]["stats"] as $stats) {
    if($highest_name === false || $stats['value'] > $highest_value) {
        $highest_name = $stats['name'];
        $highest_value = $stats['value'];
    }
}

print $highest_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$fav_gun1 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["9"]["value"];
$fav_gun2 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["10"]["value"];
$fav_gun3 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["11"]["value"];
$fav_gun4 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["12"]["value"];
$fav_gun5 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["13"]["value"];
$fav_gun6 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["14"]["value"];
$fav_gun7 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["15"]["value"];
$fav_gun8 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["16"]["value"];
$fav_gun9 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["17"]["value"];
$fav_gun10 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["18"]["value"];
$fav_gun11 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["19"]["value"];
$fav_gun12 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["20"]["value"];
$fav_gun13 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["21"]["value"];
$fav_gun14 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["22"]["value"];
$fav_gun15 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["23"]["value"];
$fav_gun16 = (int) $stats["playerstats"]["stats"]["24"]["value"];

$fav_guns_tab = array($fav_gun1, $fav_gun2, $fav_gun3, $fav_gun4, $fav_gun5, $fav_gun6, $fav_gun7, $fav_gun8, $fav_gun9, $fav_gun10, $fav_gun11, $fav_gun12, $fav_gun13, $fav_gun14, $fav_gun15, $fav_gun16);

$fav_gun = array_keys($fav_guns_tab, max($fav_guns_tab));
```

Comment: Try and enforce the int conversion of the id you get from $fav_gunX = ... that returns a string. "3" is different from 3. one is  string(1) "3" and the other is int(3)